# Edit Page Section based on Role

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

Is there a way to assign a section of a page to a Group for editing?

This is a hypothetical concept for implementation

### For example

- SysOp group can Edit all sections available on a page
- Republican group can Edit only those sections on a page defined for Republican edits
- Democrat group can Edit only those sections on a page defined for Democrat edits
- Independent group can Edit only those sections on a page defined for Indepedents
- Media group can add content to the Media references

I also have a scenario where I want to have a Data driven section to show the "facts" without interpretation and would need to isolate that information from any non-Bot from editing.

Answer (score 1):

No, MediaWiki does not have a concept of sections internally, section editing is just UI sugar on top of page editing. There are ways to prevent editing a part of the page (e.g. the [ProtectSection](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ProtectSection) extension does that), but MediaWiki wasn't built to support that kind of thing; I would not rely on it.

What you can do is make a page like

```
=== Republicans ===
{{ {{{PAGENAME}}}/Republicans }}

=== Democrats ===
{{ {{{PAGENAME}}}/Republicans }}

=== Independents ===
{{ {{{PAGENAME}}}/Independents }}
```

to transclude each section from a separate page, and only allow sysops to edit the main page, sysops and republicans to edit the `/Republican` subpage etc.

Comment: Yeah I was hoping not to do Transclusion but seems to be the only way to obtain the desired effect.

Comment: In theory.....wouldnt it be better to put the Header code on the Transcluded page instead of the "Parent" page?  That way if they are disallowed from editing, they won't get the `edit` link?

Comment: That's probably better, yeah. (Also it would make the edit link go to the right place.)